# Controlling volume density

Tags: rendering, volumetrics

How can I control the volume density values at different locations in a mesh with [volume shaders](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Materials/Volume)?

I know that noise textures can be plugged in to the density factor slot of a volume shader (producing a sponge-like effect as in the example below) for instance, but what other ways are there to control the density pattern inside a mesh? Are there ways to achieve more controlled/less random patterns?

[image: noise volume texture example]

Comment: You can use any texture you want.. What kind of pattern do you have in mind?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Yes**, you can use any set of 3D values (e.g. [procedural texture](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Types/Procedural)) you want (note that this means you can't use image textures. This is because you need the texture to be defined in 3D, and of course a image texture is 2D.
See [the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Textures) for a list of cycles textures with descriptions.

The density is controlled by the *value* (brightness) of the texture.
Consider this node setup:

[image]

Where the texture is white (`1`), the density will be `1`. Where it is black (`0`), the density will be `0`.

Because a density of 1 is still very faint, I have added a multiply node to scale the white portions of the texture to `20` instead of 1:

[image]

As an example for non-procedural texture information, this setup will make the density based on the global X location of the object (with some math nodes to avoid volumes with negative density):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have used the other procedural textures with volume shaders as well. What I mean to ask is, are we 'limited' to the current selection of procedural textures, or are there other ways to define the volume density at different points inside a mesh? Is there a way to make the density at a point a function of its local or global coordinates, for instance (set the density equal to the tangent of the local x coordinate at that point)? Are there ways to switch to different volume shader subtrees if the z coordinate is between 1 and 3 blender units away from the local object origin? And how...

Comment: @Qutorial You don't have to use procidural textures, anything that returns a value will work.

Comment: Is there a rule of thumb or list of what's compatible with the density input (what sockets will output a density field/values in 3 dimensions)?

Comment: @Qutorial In general everything *works*, but things which are inherently 2D don't give you very obviously useful results (no doubt you could find some creative use for them). Experiment and see what happens :)