# How to make a crystal material?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

How to make a crystal material in cycles with the node editor?
Much like this - [image: crystal material]

Not exactly like the image because I'm trying to make an object with a light that is emitting from the center of the object lighting it towards the surface of the object as the light fades. And the object to be crystal like looking (the back faces to be visible too, like a real crystal). The "layer weight" node does something like that, but it shows the materials according to the camera angles and I don't want that. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using volume rendering, you can emit light from inside a glass object. If you use a procedural gradient texture to control the strength, you get a nice effect:

[image]

[image]

If you bump up the IOR, it helps make it look more like a crystal:

[image]

Also see
[Controlling volume density](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8130/599)

---

## Original answer:

You can make a glass object emit light on other objects without affecting the appearance of the object to the camera with a *light path* node:

[image]

If the incoming ray is a

- Camera ray
- Transmission ray
- Glossy Ray

Then the glass shader is used. If it's not any of the above, then the emission shader is used. If the ray is hitting the back of a face, it always uses the glass shader.

If you want you could also add some emission which is visible to the camera, to make it appear more glowy:

[image]

If you want light to be emitted from *inside* the object, you can use the new volumetrics features:

[image]

Comment: @Vladimir Not sure why that would be.. Could you upload a .blend or something?

Comment: @Vladimir I'm not sure I know what you want.. The layer weight node gives a value between 1 and 0 based on the angle of the incoming ray and the face. The second example uses this to emit more light from faces at grazing angles, but I used a fresnel node instead of a layer weight node. You could use the fresnel socket of the layer weight node to get the exact same result, only the input units are different.. To control the amount of emitted light regardless of angle you can just change the strength of the emission node.

Comment: @Vladimir No, only in the last example is light emitted from inside the object. As far as I can see your question doesn't mention anything about emitting light from inside an object, so I didn't take that into account for the first few examples..

Comment: @Vladimir Does the third example work for you? If not, Is it possible you could make a mockup/example/reference image of exactly how you want it to look?

Comment: @Vladimir What about the last example?

Comment: (I was making a change of the comment and a half got deleted) - Your last example is good, its just that I want to be able to control the amount of emition and I want the light to emit from the center of the object lighting it outwards as the light fades toward the ground. Maybe something what the "layer weight - facing" node does, but the issue with it is that the materials are shifting from one to another depending on the camera angle as the camera rotates around it and I don't want that. What can I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16021/discussion-between-gandalf3-and-vladimir).

Comment: It requires me to log in again and it won't log me in for some reason. Its like this - When you have two materials plugged in a mix shader and then a "layer weight" in the factor value. When a face of an object is facing directly to the camera, it is 100 % the first material and when that face is rotated 90 degrees it is 100 % the other material. That's not what I want. I want simply a glass or crystal like material where there is light emitting from its center outward, lighting the object as the light fades away. The last image in the chat is a lot like what I want. How do you do it?

Comment: @Vladimir Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KGC1g.png)?

Comment: Much like that. How?