# how can i create these two similar yet somewhat different energy/light based items?

Tags: modeling, materials, objects, particles, light

[image]i seek to create two items,one is a "chaos emerald" from the sonic the hedgehog series (mainly as a concept and training) and the other is a sword or other bladed weapon with energy/light running along or around the regular metal blade.

i have looked up many tutorials for mechanics similar to what i need for the emerald but none of them come out quite as it should. (i need it to be a light/energy emitting almost perfect colored diamond type item that doesn't have many faces to it {roughly 6 sided diamond shape}).

For the sword/bladed weapon it essentially has a halo energy sword type blade running along the side of the regular metal blade. or energy running through different parts of the blade.

[image: energy blade]

Comment: It would be useful to include a Blender screen capture of you work, success or failure, or images of approximations of what you want to achieve.   Blender is visual, include some visuals.  Guessing what you want is inefficient. Please show the reader what you want. IMHO IIHO it would help the clarity of your question and display more effort.  If you need a tutorial series ,  here is one ..........  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY6KPrc4uMw&list=PLda3VoSoc_TR7X7wfblBGiRz-bvhKpGkS

Comment: This might help http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14465/how-to-make-a-crystal-material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tutorial would be beyond the scope of this website, but what I can tell you is that it largely depends on what engine you're using.

If you're using the Blender Internal renderer, you'll want to rely heavily on compositing.

If you're using the Cycles engine, you'll probably still do some compositing (for the glow) but in both cases, you'll want to work with the "Light Path" node to select which rays are actually visible in the camera. For example, if you give your crystals an emission material, then they will just look solid bright in the camera. However, if you set up a node system that doesn't show direct emission rays to the camera, then you can have the emission material cast light around the scene, but have the crystal look in the camera.

Take a look at the node setup on the SECOND answer on [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17910/how-to-make-a-cycles-light-emisson-object-invisible-to-the-camera). The "Is Camera Ray" is piped into the Fac of a Mix Shader. This means that if the ray is directly visible by the camera, it will use the bottom shader and the camera will see a transparent material for that object. HOWEVER, if the ray is any OTHER kind of ray, it will use the top shader and the rest of the scene will see an emission material.

Exchange that Transparent BSDF for a really cool crystal-type material, and you'll see a crystal that casts light all over the scene.

The only problem with this setup is when the crystal is actually visible in the reflection of ANOTHER object. The emission shader will be visible in the reflection, not the crystal shader. So just be careful how you use it.

Hope that helps!