# Volumetric gradient based on density?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, volumetrics

I am trying to make a material that is translucent at the surface and opaque in the middle.  How can I control the gradient?

I would like the gradient to correspond with the mesh; i.e. not simply radiate from the origin or something like that.  (If my model was a tree, the leaves and bark would be translucent while the branches and trunk, under a couple inches of bark, would be opaque.)

For reference, I am trying to replicate this glacial ice:

[image]

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/controlling-volume-density is similar to what I'm asking but the answers were unclear.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [absorption node](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Materials/Volume#Volume_Shaders) seems to be what you are looking for.

[image]

You can also add surface shaders on top of the volume shaders, for example:

[image]