# Trying to fake "God Rays"/ Stage Lights with materials

Tags: node-editor, volumetrics

I feel like this could be done but a combination of math nodes but I have no clue how to set it up.

I have a spot light with a cone parented to it.

The cone has scatter and absorption.

Is there a way to get rid of the black volume? I just want the light to fade out to transparency. I have tried the gradient nodes but its not working. This is the closest I can get.

[image]

[image]

I am looking for something like this

[image]

Comment: if you add an alpha channel that dilutes the black?

Comment: Have you tried  taking out the volume absorption node?

Comment: Similar question: [Creating realistic concert lighting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82230/creating-realistic-concert-lighting/82233#82233)

Comment: And : [How to make Volumetric Scatter fade adjustable](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/70271/how-to-make-volumetric-scatter-fade-adjustable/70272#70272)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use just the emission for the volume:
[image]

EDIT:
Just to give you an idea how it can look like with just emission and render really fast:
[image]

Comment: This works very well for what I need it for. Do you have any idea what the math nodes are doing?

Comment: In my example they are just for mapping the volume gradient from 1, close to light to 0, far from light source

Answer (score 2):

Well I think the gradient might be at least some help to you, if you hook it up to the density.  Here is an example with a linear gradient:

[image: spotlamp with volume gradient]

Here is the same image with the gradient disconnected:

[image: spotlamp with no gradient]

It is true that if there is ambient lighting, a certain amount of volume particles may be visible:

[image: spotlamp with ambient light]

Some of that could be mitigated by strategic repositioning of your spot lamp:

[image]

and/or dialing back the gradient, for example by altering the "location" component of the mapping node (here I set the X coordinate to -0.2):

[image]

Hopefully these give you some ideas for tweaking your setup.  (By the way, I did not end up making use of the Multiply node in the group below, but it's another parameter you could play with).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of volumetric lighting you are trying to make, volumetric lighting is simple to set up.

1. First create a cone (since you are trying to make God Rays) and place it over the desired object. In the object tab under "Display", change Maximum Draw Type to Wire[image]
2. Next, add a new material to the cone, and under "Volume" select Volume Scatter [image]
3. Create a spot light lamp and place it above the cone[image]
4. Now select the material added to the cone, open the node editor and have the Volume Scatter node connected to "Volume" on the Material Output. Your node setup should look like the picture below. After doing so you can change the density of the Volume Scatter and change the strength of the spot light lamp to get the desired effect. [image]
5. You should get a rendered result of something similar to this: [image: Here, the strength of the spot light is 600, and the Volume Scatter density is 0.1]