# Spotlights in Blender Cycles

Tags: light, lighting

I'm working a lot on creating Eurovision and other "concert-performance" stages, and I want to equip the stage with lots of spotlights. The problem is that the spotlights always turn out really harsh, no matter what I do to tweak the settings. Is there anyone who knows how to make realistic spotlights in Cycles (that kind of have the same effect as the ones in the Blender Render)? As seen in the first image, the end of the spotlight is very hard, instead of the soft light that a spotlight would emit. Sorry for potentially bad English. [image: Here is one of the solutions I've tried, but still a bit too harsh on the edges]

[image: Here's the first solution I tried, just moving the emission node to volume instead of surface. Too "hard" edges..]

Comment: For lights to behavior in that manner in a realistic render engine you have to understand the real physical reason why lights look like that at all in a staged environment. I would say these lights are heavily dependent on volumetric setting in the scene. Without some kind of volumetric smoke real lights just will not look like this, Plus such environment are really dark and lights usually focus and narrow. If you can create the volumetric environment you will have that "look" of light in cycles. My I ask if you have what you want in blender internal why bother with cycles?

Comment: This might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101114/trying-to-fake-god-rays-stage-lights-with-materials

Comment: @hawkenfox The reason is the more realistic lighting that Cycles offers. But thank you!