# Volumetric light without fog

Tags: light, volumetrics

I'm using blender 2.8.

I was wondering is there any way to create volumetric light without fog (or just a little bit) ? There are some tutorials on Youtube but almost all of them are creating volumetric scatter to show the light paths but I don't want this. I just want sharp light paths.

Here are some images that are similar to what i want:

[image: Volumetric ligh example 1]
[image: Volumetric light example 2]

Comment: You are searching for "god rays". Easy to achieve using the compositor (glare node or sunbeams):  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12218/how-to-make-sunbeams-in-blender, and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/101114/trying-to-fake-god-rays-stage-lights-with-materials

Answer (score 0):

Try this [image: node setup]
The result [image: looks like this]
You can parent the plane to the object that casts the rays, add to it constrain "Track To", choose your camera and play with constrain's settings. Also you can render it from another scene and than mix with original scene using compositor

Comment: Thanks for you help
I did every thing and it was great but there is a big problem and that is it doesnt respond to other objects
i mean for example if you look at the first image: there is a tree and when light hit it, it doesnt make light paths anymore
i could do something if it was a still image but i wanna make and animation so...
but thank you anyway I changed my mind and im doing something else
but i will be happy if you help me even more to make what i want

Comment: With a little effort it can be easily done on compositing. For example after your scene is ready you can link the plane with rays and your active camera to another scene, duplicate all objects which are meant to be obstacles, replace their materials with holdout shader and move them to that rays scene. All you have to do after that is mix those two scenes in Compositor using Alpha Over if your rays scene render is semitransparent, or Mix node in Add mode if rays scene's background is black. Just one possible solution, but of course there are much more. It depends on particular scene.