# Voxel Data texture in Blender (Especially for Cycles/EEVEE)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics, procedural, eevee-render-engine

**What I'm up to?**
I would like to render some CT/MRI data. The data is represented as a 3d array with float values. (Or a sequence of 2d images)

**My scheme**
As [the blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/types/procedural/introduction.html) describes, procedual textures have their 3D structure.
With the trick in the stack exchange QA (
[Controlling volume density](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/controlling-volume-density)), this 3D structure can be visualised.

Thus, all I need to do is to **convert the 3d array to a 3D texture**.
Please help me achieve this either by **node** or **scripting**(preferred).
Thanks.

---

**Edit**
The picture below shows that the single image version is rather simple.

[image: Single_Image_version]

The following is the .blend file for the above screen shot. (Although, you might not have the image texture with it.)

[image]

The tasks above can be achieved in Blender Internal (see comments). I am now eager to know a Cycles/EEVEE solution

Comment: If you are happy with single image, why not to load all scans as image sequence and render that way? Just rename images in specific app to get names like scan_001, scan_002 and so on.

Comment: @SergeL Thanks for the reply. One of the advantage of rendering them with one cube is that I can keep the geometry-size small. Although your proposal may be one of the possible solutions, I don't want to see a cube on a cube on a cube ... on a cube, until it piles up to 1000.

Comment: found this. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/blender_render/textures/types/volume/voxel_data.html (I think I can solve this myself but still open for any kind of answer/advice)

Comment: The link above is well explained in the following video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7PSPiUrrXsg. However, this is not a promising solution since this uses Blender Internal Renderer. Any Cycles/EEVEE solution is more preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not available for the Cycles/EEVEE. However, one of the GSoC 2018 challenge aims to implement this. https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Geraldine/GSoC_2018/Proposal

I will update this post once it is available.

Comment: Any updates yet?

Comment: Not quite. The branch for this is at https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/history/soc-2018-cycles-volumes/ but I cannot judge how this project went or how this would influence the blender source. Speaking of OpenVDB, the Sculpt team seems to be interested in using OpenVDB for re-meshing but that's yet another area so ...